# How to create a java.lang.Class object from byte[] (Bytecode)?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, javassist, bytecode-manipulation

I created an agent to transform code and add some classes at runtime. Therefore I need to change the code of these classes (located in the jar file of the agent) which will get added in order for my application to work well.  I managed transform the Bytecode of these classes to my needs.

Is it possible to create a java.lang.Class with this modified Bytecode?

```java
for(Class c : agentClassesToTransform) {
    byte[] modifiedBytes = editClass(c);

    Class editedClass;

    // create class using the modified bytes

    ...

    addClassToClassloader(editedClass);
}
```

Comment: See if java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass() does what you want

Comment: Return the bytecode when the `transform​` method of your `ClassFileTransformer` is invoked with the desired `ClassLoader` and class name.